# uploading files from one domain to another in laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I am kinda stuck in my laravel 5.2 application (I'm actually a newbie in Laravel). I am working on a project with both front and back ends. The two ends are hosted on two different domains (frontend on the main domain and backend on a subdomain). The problem is, am trying to upload files (images) from the backend on the subdomain to a folder on the main domain. I have made extensive research on how to do this to no avail. Hoping to get assisted. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should take a look at Laravel filesystem, it could help : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the upload form on the same server that the request is procesed and try to include the form on the other server using an iframe or something similar.